# Verifying Equations for the Volume of Three Roofed Buildings

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

I am rewriting a legacy application to a web environment and it does quite a bit in terms of geometric calculations. So far, everything I've seen I've been able to make sense of, but I've come to a series of volume calculations for buildings with different roofs that I haven't been able to verify the accuracy of. Apologies for any lack of clarity of the drawings, the original images I have to go on are much smaller.

The first I'm fairly confident in: [it's a Gable Roof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BiUp.png)

$w$ = the shorter side of the building

$l$ = the longer side of the building

$h_{base}$ = the height from the floor to the base of the roof

$h_{total}$ = the height from the floor to the top of the roof

The second I'm not as confident in: [it's a Hip Roof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vabe.png)

The third is the kicker: [I can't find a name for this one, so I call it Flat Mansard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEqQS.png)

$\theta$ = the angle between the slope of the roof and the side - 90 degrees, otherwise being the angle formed if you removed the rectangular prism that comprises the base of the building

The section in the middle of the roof is flat, and made me think originally it was a Hip Roof that had a section cut out of it.

What I'm looking for is verification that these equations are correct for the determination of the volume of these buildings and, optionally, an explanation as to what the third roof's equations are doing.

EDIT: Apologies, for the last set of equations I forgot to transcribe properly. For each $h$ assume it's $(h_{total} - h_{base})$

Comment: The formulas are correct, but bear in mind that the formula for the Hip Roof is only valid if the four sloping planes make angles of $45^o$ with the horizontal

Comment: Thanks! How would I change the Hip Roof formulas to work with a variable angle? [because as you correctly surmised there is a variable angle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you label the angle between the end slopes and the horizontal as $A$ in degrees, or $\frac{A\pi}{180}$ in radians (as is the convention with the third formula), then you need to change the formulas for the Hip Roof as follows:

Let $x=\frac{h}{\tan A}$, then
$$v_2=\frac{(l-2x)wh}{2}$$
$$v_3=\frac{2xwh}{3}$$

$v_1$ is the same as before (the volume of the base cuboid) and the total is $$v_1+v_2+v_3$$ as before.

Note that following your notation, $h$ is the difference between total height and base cuboid height.

Another observation: the formula for the third roof assumes that all four sloping faces are at the same angle to the horizontal.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thanks! The third roof has equivalent angles on all 4 sides, so that's not a worry but useful to know!